# Play framework, scala forms set default value

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.2

I'm using play framework 2.2, how can I set default value in form? I want to user see 1000 as default timeout:

My form:

```
val deviceForm = Form(mapping(
  "name" -> nonEmptyText,
  "timeout" -> number
  )(Device.apply)(Device.unapply))
```

in view:

```
@inputText(deviceForm("name"), '_label -> "Name")
@inputText(deviceForm("timeout"), '_label -> "Timeout")
```

Answer (score 5):

Just use 'default' in your form field

```
val deviceForm = Form(mapping(
   "name" -> nonEmptyText,
   "timeout" -> default(number, 1000)
)(Device.apply)(Device.unapply))
```

Comment: Seems to be broken in play 2.7

Comment: No, it's still there: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/api/scala/play/api/data/Forms$.html

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
val filled = deviceForm.fill(Device(name,timeout))
```

Where `name` and `timeout` are the values you want.

Comment: I also in Device have a field server, when I'm trying to fill using null as server I'm getting null pointer exception, and what if I don't have a server yet, and want just display a form?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use a `placeholder` for your defaults;
here is an example for yourcase;

```
@inputText(deviceForm("name"), '_label -> "Name", 'placeholder -> "Default Name")
@inputText(deviceForm("timeout"), '_label -> "Timeout", 'placeholder -> "Default Timeout")
```

Comment: This will simply print an indication to the user but the field will still be empty when clicking on the submit button.